# Installing and getting a python module to work on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I tried to install the module `twilio` with `pip` on my mac running El Capitan and it showed the following:

```
~ $ pip install twilio
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twilio in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2>=0.7 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from twilio)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from twilio)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from twilio)
 ~ $ python
Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import twilio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .rest.exceptions import TwilioRestException
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import set_twilio_proxy
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.resources import Connection
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .util import (
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/util.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pytz
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

Then I tried installing pytz and it says I already have it:

```
~ $ pip install pytz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

Is it caused by the fact that I have different Python distributions on my mac? I searched for a while and people are saying that pip only installs to the default Python, it's better to use MacPort, Homebrew with virtualenv to manage python distributions. But what I really want to do here is just to solve this particular problem directly. I ran `type -a python` I saw from another post and it yields,

```
~ $ type -a python
python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

They are all Python 2.7.10, the first two seem to be the same. (I found out that they are the Python.org Python.)

I don't know how to switch between them in terminal, or pip install the packages separately for them. I guess it's a common problem but I couldn't solve it with an hour of searching around.

---

To be clear, I have added some more info here,

```
~ $ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

~ $ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

~ $ /usr/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

~ $ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 22 2015, 20:33:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pip` instance you are using is probably associated with the system Python while the `python` command is invoking the python.org Python.  One way to avoid such mismatches is to invoke `pip` via the command you use to invoke `python`, in this case:

```
python -m pip install twilio
```

That will ensure that you are using the right `pip` and that the packages are installed to the right locations for the Python in use.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did it! But I still have some doubts. Is there a way to directly check which `python` `pip` is associated with currently?

Comment: The `pip` command is a Python script.  You can examine the "shebang" line  of it to see the path of the Python interpreter it will use when invoked directly (rather than via `python -m`).  If you are using a POSIX-compatible shell, like `bash`, the following command should work: `head -1 $(type -p pip)`